# How to Post Multi-select Values to SugarCRM via Rest API?

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm, multi-select

Anyone have knowledge on how to insert multiple value from a multiselect input in a form via sugar's REST API v4. I haven't found any documentation on this.  The following inserts 1 value correctly but I'm stuck on saving multiple values:

```
function getSugar($method, $parameters){
    $url = 'https://****.sugarondemand.com/service/v4/rest.php';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = json_encode($parameters);
    $postArgs = array(
         'method' => $method,
         'input_type' => 'JSON',
         'response_type' => 'JSON',
         'rest_data' => $json
          );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
         die("Connection Failure.\n");
     }
     $result = json_decode($response);
     if ( !is_object($result) ) {
         die("Error handling result.\n");
     }
     if($method == "set_entry" || $method == "login"){
         if ( !isset($result->id) ) {
              die("Error: {$result->name} - {$result->description}\n.");
         }
         $id = $result->id;
         return $id;
      }else{
         if ( !is_object($result) ) {
             var_dump($response);
             die("Error handling result.\n");
          }
          return true;
     }
}

$x = "ABC";
$parameters = array(
    'session' => $sessionId,
    'module' => 'Leads',
    'name_value_list' => array(
         array('name' => 'programs_c', 'value' => $x),
         ),
 );
 $method = "set_entry";
 $leadID = getSugar($method, $parameters);
```

The field "programs_c" is a custom multiselect field in sugar with several dropdown values. I've tried running a for-each loop but that only inserts the last value.  I've also attempted nearly every possible variation of inserting an array within the array without any success.  Any help is much appreciated!  I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  Thanks in advance for any insight / direction on how to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does putting the field contents in this format work?

```
^value1^,^value2^,^value3^
```

Comment: jmetric - thank you! I did the following and it worked perfectly:  array('name' => 'programs_c', 'value' => '^ABC^,^EFG^'),

Comment: This worked like charm. I literally dont get their logic of doing like this and they haven't mentioned it somewhere to do like this

Answer (score 0):

Here's some methods I wrote to help build the multiselect query string.

```
private static function convertMultiSelectValueToArray($multiString) {
    return explode(",", $multiString);
}

/**
 * @param $notifyUser
 * @param $manageContacts
 * @param string $currMultiSelectString
 * @return string
 *
 * Examples:
 * print SugarCRM::buildRelationshipMultiselect(true,true) . "\n";  -->  ^Notify of New Updates^,^AllowManageContacts^
 * print SugarCRM::buildRelationshipMultiselect(false,true) . "\n"; --> ^AllowManageContacts^
 * print SugarCRM::buildRelationshipMultiselect(false,false, PERMISSION_ALLOW_USER_TO_MANAGE_CONTACTS . "," . PERMISSION_NOTIFY_OF_NEW_UPDATES . ",^SomeOtherThingThatShouldStillBeHere^") . "\n"; --. ^AllowManageContacts^
 */
public static function buildRelationshipMultiselect($notifyUser, $manageContacts, $currMultiSelectString='') {
    $arr = array();
    if( !empty($currMultiSelectString) ) {
        $arr = SugarCRM::convertMultiSelectValueToArray($currMultiSelectString);
    }

    // Remove them so we dont get duplicates & so they are removed if booleans are false...
    if( count($arr) > 0 ) {
        $arr = SugarCRM::removeElementFromArray($arr,PERMISSION_NOTIFY_OF_NEW_UPDATES);
        $arr = SugarCRM::removeElementFromArray($arr,PERMISSION_ALLOW_USER_TO_MANAGE_CONTACTS);
    }

    if( $notifyUser ) {
        $arr[] = PERMISSION_NOTIFY_OF_NEW_UPDATES;
    }

    if( $manageContacts ) {
        $arr[] = PERMISSION_ALLOW_USER_TO_MANAGE_CONTACTS;
    }

    return implode(",", $arr);
}

public function createNewContactRelatedToAccount($firstName,$lastName,$emailAddress,$phone,
                                                 $description,$accountId,$isManageContacts=false, $isNotifyOfUpdates=false)
{
    // TODO, check if user exists first!

    $relationships = SugarCRM::buildRelationshipMultiselect($isNotifyOfUpdates, $isManageContacts /** PUT EXISTING VALUE HERE IF UPDATING! **/);
    $sugar = new Sugar_REST( SUGAR_REST_URL, SUGAR_USER_NAME, SUGAR_PASSWORD);
    $values = array(
        'first_name' => htmlentities($firstName),
        'last_name' => htmlentities($lastName),
        'email1' => htmlentities($emailAddress),
        'description' => htmlentities($description),
        'phone_work' => htmlentities($phone),
        SUGAR_FIELDNAME_FOR_PERMISSIONS => $relationships
    );

    $contact = $sugar->set("Contacts", $values );
    $contactId = $contact['id'];
    $relStatus = $sugar->set_relationship("Accounts",$accountId, "contacts", $contactId );

    return $relStatus['created'] == 1;
}

private static function removeElementFromArray(&$search_arr, $itemToRemove) {
    // Should have just used array_search...
    foreach($search_arr as $key => $value) {
        if($value == $itemToRemove) {
            unset($search_arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $search_arr;
}
```